# Flutter : File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have already attached the google-services.json file from my firebase after connecting my flutter app and followed all the steps but I am still receiving this error. I looked for other answers on the net but none of them helped. I tried opening the app in chrome but then I recieved this error "Error: Assertion failed:
D:\…\src\firebase_core_web.dart:273
options != null
"FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."

Are these connected? What can I do to solve these?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your firebase_core version is seems to be sufficient to pass the FirebaseOptions once you initialize firebase in your flutter code.

Add this.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    // Replace with actual values
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "XXX",
      appId: "XXX",
      messagingSenderId: "XXX",
      projectId: "XXX",
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: From where can I get these values ?

Comment: Inside ` google-services.json` file and for messagingSenderId refer this https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/messaging/kms_console_user_guide/Content/Apps/Generating_Web_FCM_keys.htm#:~:text=Click%20the%20Cloud%20Messaging%20tab,ID%2C%20and%20the%20Server%20key.&text=The%20Sender%20ID%20is%20used,to%20FCM%20from%20the%20device.

Comment: I cant find the "app_Id"? Could you tell where to get that from because it is not titled app_Id in google-services.json . Is it same as "mobilesdk_app_id"?

Comment: yes, @kavyabhargava

Answer (score 1):

you need to download this “google-services.json” file and paste it inside “android>app” section. Just like this-
[image]
Then click on “Next” button. Now you need to do following changes in project-level build.gradle file.

Just like this bellow code-
[image]
After updating project-level build.gradle file, Now you have add mentioned code in App-level build.gradle file
[image]

Just like this-
[image]
[image]

Now, you have integrated firebase with flutter project.
[image]

Comment: I have done all this

Comment: the name should be google-services.json with no extra space check again might help