# Firebase AppCheck Error 403: App attestation failed

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I have added appcheck to my Flutter app. However, this does not work properly. I use Android and have entered all the keys correctly. However, every time I start the app, the following messages appear:

```
IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=<<long code>>, cloudProjectNumber=<<project number>>, network=null})
I/PlayCore(19441): UID: [10759]  PID: [19441] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore(19441): UID: [10759]  PID: [19441] IntegrityService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityService})
I/PlayCore(19441): UID: [10759]  PID: [19441] IntegrityService : linkToDeath
I/PlayCore(19441): UID: [10759]  PID: [19441] OnRequestIntegrityTokenCallback : onRequestIntegrityToken
I/PlayCore(19441): UID: [10759]  PID: [19441] IntegrityService : Unbind from service.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(19441): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed.
```

The problem is that all backend requests are unauthorised. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

please 1st verify that you have init the app check correctely.

> [**Initialize App Check**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers#initialize)
>
> Add the following initialization code to your app so that it runs
> before you use any Firebase services such as Storage, but after
> calling Firebase.initializeApp();

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

// Import the firebase_app_check plugin
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    // You can also use a `ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider` provider instance as an
    // argument for `webProvider`
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
    // Default provider for Android is the Play Integrity provider. You can use the "AndroidProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. Debug provider
    // 2. Safety Net provider
    // 3. Play Integrity provider
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    // Default provider for iOS/macOS is the Device Check provider. You can use the "AppleProvider" enum to choose
        // your preferred provider. Choose from:
        // 1. Debug provider
        // 2. Device Check provider
        // 3. App Attest provider
        // 4. App Attest provider with fallback to Device Check provider (App Attest provider is only available on iOS 14.0+, macOS 14.0+)
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );
  runApp(App());
}
```

if you believe that you have init the app check correctely thel try the following.

1. verify that `google-services.json` correctly placed in the project.
2. try to add SHA-256 key hashes in the firebase console also try by removing and adding it again.

also it may be helpful to go through following

> [**Use App Check with the debug provider with Flutter**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider)
>
> After you have registered your app for App Check, your app normally
> won't run in an emulator or from a continuous integration (CI)
> environment, since those environments don't qualify as valid devices.
> If you want to run your app in such an environment during development
> and testing, you can create a debug build of your app that uses the
> App Check debug provider instead of a real attestation provider.

Comment: I think its the google-services.json
Where can i get it and where does it have to be?

Comment: go with [flutter-file-google-services-json-is-missing-the-google-services-plugin-canno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886849/flutter-file-google-services-json-is-missing-the-google-services-plugin-canno) and [where-do-i-place-googleservices-json-in-flutter-app-in-order-to-solve-google-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783588/where-do-i-place-googleservices-json-in-flutter-app-in-order-to-solve-google-se) and let know if it helps

Comment: ok this was in place and fine
when I try `AndroidProvider.debug` insteat I get the same error